# Getting error running this code for word search

Tags: python-2.7

```
import sys
GameMatrix = [ ['S','E','A','N','T','A','R','C','I','T','R','U','R','T','O','I','I','Y'],
                   ['O','C','U','P','O','N','A','P','S','A','N','D','D','U','N','E','R','L'],
                   ['C','O','A','U','S','E','A','R','L','M','O','O','Y','N','O','S','I','N'],
                   ['E','P','O','V','A','L','L','A','A','R','R','A','A','D','F','O','R','E'],
                   ['D','R','F','L','R','D','R','Y','N','I','L','S','R','R','C','R','A','A'],
                   ['V','A','L','L','E','Y','S','A','D','Y','H','U','M','A','T','A','P','E'],
                   ['T','I','D','A','L','P','O','O','L','M','O','U','N','T','A','I','N','S'],
                   ['D','R','J','O','D','D','C','O','R','A','L','R','E','E','F','N','S','E'],
                   ['A','I','U','A','E','P','E','O','A','S','I','S','N','O','O','F','E','A'],
                   ['N','E','N','S','S','O','A','S','R','I','S','L','A','C','A','O','A','F'],
                   ['T','D','G','S','E','D','A','L','C','E','H','U','M','E','A','R','F','L'],
                   ['A','E','L','D','P','I','I','T','T','A','O','L','A','K','E','E','L','O'],
                   ['R','D','E','S','E','R','T','R','I','V','E','R','E','P','R','S','O','O'],
                   ['C','P','I','C','E','I','D','O','C','E','A','N','P','O','L','T','H','R'],
                   ['J','O','T','O','A','N','T','A','R','C','T','I','C','U','E','T','U','P'],
                   ['U','N','U','S','A','N','D','D','U','O','A','G','R','A','S','S','M','O'],
                   ['N','D','H','U','M','F','O','R','E','S','T','S','E','A','F','D','I','P'],
                   ['V','A','L','L','R','E','T','I','D','A','L','P','T','I','D','A','D','I'],
                   ]
wordSearch = {'antarctic','grass','oasis','sanddune','arctic','humid','ocean','sea','coralreef','island','pond','seafloor','desert','jungle','prairie','tidalpool','dry','lake','rainforest','tundra','forest','mountain','river','valley'}
def print_board(GameMatrix):
    for i in range(0,len(GameMatrix)):
        for j in range(0,len(GameMatrix[i])):
            sys.stdout.write(GameMatrix[i][j])
            sys.stdout.write(' ')
        print
def word_going_right(GameMatrix,wordSearch,row,col):
    i = 0
    f = 0
    v = True
    while v == True:
        if wordSearch[i] == GameMatrix[row][col]:
            f += 1
        if f == len(wordSearch):
            v = True
            break
        if wordSearch[i] != GameMatrix[row][col]:
            v = True
            break
        i += 1
        f += 1
        if col >= len(GameMatrix[0]):
            v = False
            break
        return v
def word_going_left(Gamematrix,wordSearch,row,col):
    i = 0
    f = 0
    v = True
    while v == True:
        if wordSearch[i] == GameMatrix[row][col]:
            f += 1
            if f == len(wordSearch):
                v = True
                break
            if wordSearch[i] != GameMatrix[row][col]:
                v = False
                break
            i += 1
            f += 1
            col -= 1
            if col <= 0:
                v = False
                break
            return v
def word_going_up(GameMatrix,wordSearch,row,col):
    i = 0
    f = 0
    v = True
    while v == True:
        if wordSearch[i] == GameMatrix[row][col]:
            f += 1
            if f == len(wordSearch):
                v = True
                break
            if wordSearch[i] != GameMatrix[row][col]:
                v = False
                break
            i += 1
            f += 1
            row -= 1
            if row <= 0:
                v = False
                break
            return v

def word_going_down(GameMatrix,wordSearch,row,col):
    i = 0
    f = 0
    v = True
    while v == True:
        if wordSearch[i] == GameMatrix[row][col]:
            f += 1
            if f == len(wordSearch):
                v = True
                break
            if wordSearch[i] != GameMatrix[row][col]:
                v = False
                break
            i += 1
            row += 1
            if row >= len(GameMatrix):
                v = False
                break
            return v
def find_word_in_puzzle(GameMatrix,wordSearch):
    value = True
    new_row = 0
    new_col = 0
    direction = ''
    for r in range(0,len(GameMatrix)):
        for c in range(0,len(GameMatrix)):
            if word_going_right(GameMatrix,wordSearch,r,c) == True:
                new_row = r
                new_col = c
                direction = 'right'
                value = True
                break
            if word_going_left(GameMatrix,wordSearch,r,c) == True:
                new_row =r
                new_col = c
                direction = 'left'
                value = True
                break
            if word_going_up(GameMatrix,wordSearch,r,c) == True:
                new_row = r
                new_col = c
                direction = 'up'
                value = True
                break
            if word_going_down(GameMatrix,wordSearch,r,c) == True:
                new_row = r
                new_col = c
                direction = 'down'
                value = True
                break
    if value == False:
        print "%s can't be found" % (wordSearch)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print GameMatrix
    print
    print_board(GameMatrix)
    print
    words_filename = raw_input("Enter the word= ")
    print wordSearch
    print
    for line in words_filename:
        word = line.strip()
        find_word_in_puzzle(GameMatrix, wordSearch)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordsearch.py", line 160, in <module>
    find_word_in_puzzle(GameMatrix, wordSearch)
  File "wordsearch.py", line 119, in find_word_in_puzzle
    if word_going_right(GameMatrix,wordSearch,r,c) == True:
  File "wordsearch.py", line 35, in word_going_right
    if wordSearch[i] == GameMatrix[row][col]:
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: Your `wordSearch` is a set, and you try to index it - `wordSearch[i]`. Sets have no order and no concept of indexed access.

Comment: i tried changing it, but I'm not getting the desired output. I'm doing word search in python but the output now I'm getting is:

Answer (score 0):

i tried changing it, but I'm not getting the desired output. I'm doing word search in python but the output now I'm getting is:

Last login: Tue Sep 20 18:43:59 on ttys000
dhcp-10-100-10-29:~ fahadwali$ python wordsearch.py
[['S', 'E', 'A', 'N', 'T', 'A', 'R', 'C', 'I', 'T', 'R', 'U', 'R', 'T', 'O', 'I', 'I', 'Y'], ['O', 'C', 'U', 'P', 'O', 'N', 'A', 'P', 'S', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'D', 'U', 'N', 'E', 'R', 'L'], ['C', 'O', 'A', 'U', 'S', 'E', 'A', 'R', 'L', 'M', 'O', 'O', 'Y', 'N', 'O', 'S', 'I', 'N'], ['E', 'P', 'O', 'V', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'R', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'O', 'R', 'E'], ['D', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'R', 'D', 'R', 'Y', 'N', 'I', 'L', 'S', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'A', 'A'], ['V', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'E', 'Y', 'S', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'H', 'U', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'P', 'E'], ['T', 'I', 'D', 'A', 'L', 'P', 'O', 'O', 'L', 'M', 'O', 'U', 'N', 'T', 'A', 'I', 'N', 'S'], ['D', 'R', 'J', 'O', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'O', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'N', 'S', 'E'], ['A', 'I', 'U', 'A', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'O', 'A', 'S', 'I', 'S', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'F', 'E', 'A'], ['N', 'E', 'N', 'S', 'S', 'O', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'I', 'S', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'O', 'A', 'F'], ['T', 'D', 'G', 'S', 'E', 'D', 'A', 'L', 'C', 'E', 'H', 'U', 'M', 'E', 'A', 'R', 'F', 'L'], ['A', 'E', 'L', 'D', 'P', 'I', 'I', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'L', 'A', 'K', 'E', 'E', 'L', 'O'], ['R', 'D', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'R', 'I', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'E', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'O', 'O'], ['C', 'P', 'I', 'C', 'E', 'I', 'D', 'O', 'C', 'E', 'A', 'N', 'P', 'O', 'L', 'T', 'H', 'R'], ['J', 'O', 'T', 'O', 'A', 'N', 'T', 'A', 'R', 'C', 'T', 'I', 'C', 'U', 'E', 'T', 'U', 'P'], ['U', 'N', 'U', 'S', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'D', 'U', 'O', 'A', 'G', 'R', 'A', 'S', 'S', 'M', 'O'], ['N', 'D', 'H', 'U', 'M', 'F', 'O', 'R', 'E', 'S', 'T', 'S', 'E', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'I', 'P'], ['V', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'R', 'E', 'T', 'I', 'D', 'A', 'L', 'P', 'T', 'I', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'I']]

S E A N T A R C I T R U R T O I I Y 
O C U P O N A P S A N D D U N E R L 
C O A U S E A R L M O O Y N O S I N 
E P O V A L L A A R R A A D F O R E 
D R F L R D R Y N I L S R R C R A A 
V A L L E Y S A D Y H U M A T A P E 
T I D A L P O O L M O U N T A I N S 
D R J O D D C O R A L R E E F N S E 
A I U A E P E O A S I S N O O F E A 
N E N S S O A S R I S L A C A O A F 
T D G S E D A L C E H U M E A R F L 
A E L D P I I T T A O L A K E E L O 
R D E S E R T R I V E R E P R S O O 
C P I C E I D O C E A N P O L T H R 
J O T O A N T A R C T I C U E T U P 
U N U S A N D D U O A G R A S S M O 
N D H U M F O R E S T S E A F D I P 
V A L L R E T I D A L P T I D A D I 
['ANTARCTIC', 'GRASS', 'OASIS', 'SANDUNE', 'ARCTIC', 'HUMID', 'OCEAN', 'SEA', 'CORALREEF', 'ISLAND', 'POND', 'SEAFLOOR', 'DESERT,', 'JUNGLE', 'PRAIRIE', 'TIDALPOOL', 'DRY', 'LAKE', 'RAINFOREST', 'TUNDRA', 'FOREST', 'MOUNTAIN', 'RIVER', 'VALLEY', 'MOBILE', 'COFFEE', 'TREE']